# Set starting frame to current month

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, date

I'm building a flash calendar but it's for the school year so the first frame is August of the current year and the last frame is July of the next year. This way August is frame 1, September frame 2, up until July at frame 12. That being said I wrote up some code to make the calendar start on the frame of the current month. So the returned value from `.getMonth()` for August would be 7, then I subtract 6 to equal frame 1 or August.

All works fine and dandy but it gets stuck on December for some reason. Any month after December (i.e. January - July) it just opens on December. It does this even though my `trace()` is showing the correct frame number it should be starting on.

Is there something I'm missing or am I just plain wrong?

```
stop()
//Start at current month
var done:Boolean;
if (!done) {
    //Code in here only runs once
    var date:Date = new Date();
    var which_month:int = date.getMonth();

    if(which_month < 6) {
        gotoAndStop((which_month + 6));
        trace((which_month + 6));
    } else {
        gotoAndStop((which_month - 6));
    }

    done=true;
}
```

Comment: Where does your code located? Is it a separated class or this code is on every frame?

Comment: It's on the first frame because it's only supposed to run once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this seems to do the trick

```
stop();
//Start at current month
var done:Boolean;
if (!done) {
    //Code in here only runs once
    var date:Date = new Date();
    var which_month:int = date.getMonth();
        which_month -= 7;
    if(which_month < 0)
    {
        which_month += 12;
    }

    gotoAndStop((which_month + 1));


    done=true;
}
```

The maths could be made a bit simpler, but my brain doesn't like thinking of the months as zero indexed!

Comment: I think ZuzEL's answer is much better than mine.

Comment: Thank you, but I think loxxy got the best with % operator, I did not got that when was printing my answer

Comment: Thank you, and since all answers address the problem albeit differently & Glitcher's being the first, OP did the right thing... :).

Comment: I try to avoid % and / because I heard it was quite expensive, should I rethink that?

Comment: All the answers were "right", I felt that since this one came first I should pick it. Also I don't like thinking about months in a zero index form either.

Answer (score 4):

Try it this way :

```
stop();

var done:Boolean;

if (!done) {
    var date:Date = new Date();
    gotoAndStop(((date.getMonth()+6)%12) + 1);
    done=true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
stop()
//Start at current month
var done:Boolean;
if (!done) {
    //Code in here only runs once
    var date:Date = new Date();
    var which_month:int = date.getMonth();
    which_month += which_month > 7 ? -7 : 6
    gotoAndStop(which_month);
    done=true;
}
```